# Read images from directory and pass each image with space separated python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to pass images for some x = img.jpg img1.jpg img2.jpg

So i want to pass these images by reading from a directory and pass to the "x" in python

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine os.listdir() and str.join() to get a string with file names.

```
 Directory of c:\test

04/27/2018  12:05 PM    <DIR>          .
04/27/2018  12:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/27/2018  12:05 PM                 0 img.jpg
04/27/2018  12:05 PM                 0 img1.jpg
04/27/2018  12:05 PM                 0 img2.jpg
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  12,995,120,250,880 bytes free
```

In Python, os.listdir() returns a list with all of the files and directories in the supplied path. Use os.getcwd (get current working directory) to get the path you're currently in.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'c:\\test'
>>> os.listdir(os.getcwd())
['img.jpg', 'img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']
```

Use str.join to convert a list into a string. The syntax of this command is a little confusing. But to use space, comma and tab separators use:

```
>>> w = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
>>> w
['img.jpg', 'img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']

>>> x = ' '.join(w)
>>> x
'img.jpg img1.jpg img2.jpg'

>>> x = '\t'.join(w)   # \t represents tab character
>>> x
'img.jpg\timg1.jpg\timg2.jpg'
>>> print(x)
img.jpg img1.jpg        img2.jpg

>>> x = ','.join(w)
>>> x
'img.jpg,img1.jpg,img2.jpg'
```

If you just want a list of file names you can use for processing, os.listdir() is still your friend:

```
import os

flist = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

for fname in flist:
    <do stuff with each file name here>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to python. i am trying this `images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))`

Comment: Am i doing correct `def main():
  global args
  args = parse_args()
  cv_img = []
  flist = os.listdir(os.getcwd(args.style_imgs))
  print("flist")
  print(flist)`

Comment: @Basha, your first comment looks good and should work OK. Your second comment is mostly good. However, I don't think you need the call os.getcwd. getcwd means "get current working directory" and returns the directory where it currently looks for files. If you remove the os.getcwd and just have os.listdir(args.style_imgs), then I think it will work for you. Presumably args.style_imgs is a directory path